# Flutter setState, hay alguna forma de que no reconstruya todo el árbol de Widgets?

Tags: android, flutter

Compañeros, necesito de que el evento SetState no me reconstruya todo el arbol cada vez que lo llamo. solo necesito una acción en este caso.

En un momento lo vi, pero no recuerdo donde. 
Logicamente funciona como debería: Reconstruye el arbol de widgets, generandome una nueva lista con todo lo demás. 
Bien, necesito "aislar" la acción para que solo se actualize la propiedad image con la variable _cartaSeleccionada

Alguna ayuda, o donde ir a leer. Estoy un poco perdido.

```js
class CartasSeleccionState extends State<CartasSeleccion> {
  bool _isSelected = false;
  String _cartaSeleccionada = "bgcard_b.jpg";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        height: 236.0,
        //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        child: new ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: new List.generate(22, (int index) {
              debugPrint('arbol regenerado');
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                widthFactor: 0.7,
                child: new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      //showCard(index);
                      _isSelected = true;
                      setState(() {
                        if (_isSelected) {
                          debugPrint("oks!");
                          //_cartaSeleccionada = "bgcard_b.jpg";
                        } else {
                          //_cartaSeleccionada = index.toString() + ".jpg";
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: _recursos.randomToBouble(-15, 15) * 0.01,
                        child: new Container(
                            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                            width: 110.0,
                            height: 196.0,
                            child: new Image(
                                image: new AssetImage(
                                    "assets/$_cartaSeleccionada"),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover)))),
              );
            })));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, no te olvides de agregar la etiqueta de Flutter en tu pregunta. Para eso debes hacer que cada carta sea un widget Stateful y maneje su propio estado. Te recomiendo que la lista la generes a nivel del initState para que no se vuelva a generar cada vez que haces el rebuild del widget.